# How to load ListView in Blackberry 10 Native SDK?

Tags: xml, listview, blackberry-10, native-code, datamodel

I have following XML data which is in QString/QByteArray.

```
<MainData version="5" entireSeasonProductId="some_Id">
<Season id="1" sProductId="some_Id">
    <Episode chapter="1" eProductId="some_Id">
        <Audio>
            <Content contentId="030101" name="name1" singer="Singer1" duration="08:44" url="some_url_link" crbt="" crbtcode=""/>
            <Content contentId="030102" name="name2" singer="Singer2" duration="8:23" url="some_url_link" crbt="" crbtcode=""/>
        </Audio>
    </Episode>
    <Episode chapter="2" eProductId="some_Id">
        <Audio>
            <Content contentId="030101" name="name1" singer="Singer1" duration="08:44" url="some_url_link" crbt="" crbtcode=""/>
            <Content contentId="030102" name="name2" singer="Singer2" duration="8:23" url="some_url_link" crbt="" crbtcode=""/>
        </Audio>
    </Episode>
</Season>
</MainData>
```

I want to show `name` , `singer` and `duration` on ListView.

Also tell me how can I pass `Season Id` and `Episode chapter no.` to fetch exact data of my expected inputs.

NOTE: There can be multiple `<Season>` tag and multiple `<Episode>` tag which is having number of `<Content>` in `<Audio>` tag.

Anyone please help me to do same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/cascades/device_platform/data_access/using_data_source.html, this might help you.

Comment: This is also a good example project showing how to do this:
https://github.com/blackberry/Cascades-Samples/tree/master/stampcollector

Comment: From [ListView documentation](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__listview.html) "_The DataModel can contain items in a tree structure many levels deep, but ListView only shows items from the first two levels below the root element (see rootIndexPath)._" In other words, if you want three levels you will probably need listview inside listview